# Quoting with thousands separator

Tags: awk, printf, quoting

awk can print numbers with a thousands separator character:

```
$ awk "BEGIN {printf \"%'d\", 1000}"
1,000
```

However the fact that it requires a single quote means that you have to escape
every `"` and `$` in the entire script:

```
$ echo 1000 2000 | awk "{printf \"%'d\", \$2}"
2,000
```

This is easy enough here but could be troublesome with large examples. I thought
of doing something like this:

```
$ echo 1000 2000 | awk '{printf z, $2}' z="%'d"
2,000
```

but even this is not great for advanced examples:

```
$ echo 1000 2000 | awk '{printf "hello " z " world " z, $1, $2}' z="%'d"
hello 1,000 world 2,000
```

I tried messing with `OFMT` and `CONVFMT`, but they seem to have no effect:

```
$ echo 1000 2000 | awk '{print $2}' OFMT="%'d" CONVFMT="%'d"
2000
```

Can those variables be used in the way I am trying to use them, or is another
method available that better deals with the quoting issue?

Comment: I think I'd probably go with `awk -f script.awk` to avoid the issue of quotes altogether.  If necessary, I'd use a here document, probably with a quoted marker (`<< 'EOF'`), to create the script.  And you might even be able to use Bash [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to avoid an explicitly named temporary file, though I don't think that would be easy to read.  And there's always the 'five carefully selected quotes' technique:  `awk 'BEGIN {printf  "%'"'"'d", 1000}'` or the canonical `awk 'BEGIN {printf  "%'\''d", 1000}'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To embed a single quote char in a single-quote-delimited command-line script just use the octal escape sequence `\047` wherever you want the quote:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%\047d\n", 1000}'
1,000
```

Bonus Points: Do not use the equivalent hex escape sequence `\x27`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "\047foo!\047"}'
'foo!'
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "\x27foo!\x27"}'
oo!'
```

See http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote

Comment: You can do it `awk 'BEGIN {print "\x27""foo\x27"}'`

Comment: Yeah you can get the output you want but there's just no point having to remember how to deal with the caveats of `\x27` vs just using `\047`.

Answer (score 0):

This builds on [Ed’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32415163), will print
separator whenever `%d` is found:

```
awk '
func t(u) {
  return gensub("%d", "%\047d", "g", u)
}
{
  printf t("hello %d world %d"), $1, $2
}
'
```